# Penis Growth After Puberty Possible

Tags: sexuality

Was reading [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigdickproblems/comments/1x81ci/help_please_penis_growth_in_later_life_having/) on Reddit. Seems to good to be true. Can penis growth happen after you're already done growing? What would be the scientific basis for this?

Comment: The purpose of this site is to investigate [notable](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-does-notable-mean) claims.  An anonymous Reddit post doesn't meet that standard.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've heard this claim more often, especially on the Internet. Unfortunately I can't disclose my sources, but your source mentions: "Naturally, a notable claim will have many mentions doing a quick Google search. When Google does not seem to return examples of it, we need to demonstrate notability."